# Finding the main activity for an Android application

Tags: java, android, apk

I have a custom launcher and at times want to add a button to launch third party applications. To do this I need the apps package name, which is easy to find, but also the apps main or starting activity. I use this to create Intents that I pass to my app.

For example, to create an intent that launches Skype I use:

```
`new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"))
```

I was able to find the name of the main activity by Googling around and as Skype is a popular app it showed up eventually.

I know that if I have the APK I can just open it and look at the androidmainifest , however I'm not sure how to get the APK's of some apps at all. For instance, I want to start [this app from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dbapp.android.mediahouse&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd) . I can see the package name, `com.dbapp.android.mediahouse`, however I'm not sure how to get the name of the main activity(I tried .MAIN).

I've looked at the Chrome extension [apk downloader](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/) that supposendly allowed you to get APK's from Google Play but it appears to no longer work.

I know starting third party apps from a custom launcher is something that must be fairly common, but I'm not finding the answer when I search.

How do people typically handle this issue? Do you get the APK from the Google Play Store and if so how does one do that? Again, I know that I can get the activity from reading the manifest but I don't know how to get the APK itself in many cases. Any advice would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: use the action main and category launcher to find the intent to use to start an app

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for the reply. I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A launcher should be finding the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` activities advertised by apps on the device, by using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) that implements such a launcher.

```
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
Intent main=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);

main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);
```

You then use that `List<ResolveInfo>` to display the available activities in a `ListView`, `GridView`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `PackageManager` offers a method to get exactly what you want:

```
PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(String packageName)
```

Comment: There's a slight caveat, though: this will return an intent for CATEGORY_INFO if one exists rather than for CATEGORY_LAUNCHER.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.MAIN);`

or like the example behind to launch Maps and parse a URI:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + Utils.getLatitude(ShowDetails.this)+","+Utils.getLongitude(ShowDetails.this)+"&daddr="+userLatitude+","+userLongitude;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I'm not sure how this is relevant to actually finding APKS and getting the activities for the APK.